# NPM version discrepancy between main version and cpanel version

Tags: node.js

When running `npm-version` on my local server/laptop I receive `7.5.6`

However, when running on cpanel terminal -- I receive

```
[~]# /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/npm --version
6.14.11
```

And this 6.14.11 is after I ran

`[~]# /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/npm install --latest version -g`

Which I thought would update it to the 7.5.6 as I used the same command to update the one on my computer as well.

In all I'm having trouble deploying my webapp on bluehost via cpanel. Even though the app is registered with the application manager -- and the Ensure Dependencies part came out done and successful. And the git repo is cloned and deployed with no errors.

Would this discrepancy be causing the app not to launch?

I can't understand why it isn't deploying properly, so I was thinking there may be something with the package.json or (package-lock.json) -- ei - could the versions in such bet preventing deployment due to discrepancies.

Would love some help, been trying to get this deployed for days!

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vandenbergdevelopment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "DeltaDesignServer",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "J Vandenberg",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.5.0",
    "hover.css": "^2.3.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.18",
    "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^2.0.2",
    "version": "^0.0.4"
  }
}
```

The top bit to the lock.json

```
 "": {
      "name": "vandenbergdevelopment",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "version": "^0.0.4",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "ejs": "^3.1.6",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "firebase-tools": "^9.5.0",
        "hover.css": "^2.3.2",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.18",
        "nodemailer-mailgun-transport": "^2.0.2"
      }
    },
```

Thank you!

Comment: My assumption is that you don't have node 10 loaded on your local system, that you have a newer version installed, probably node 15.

Comment: Ah thank you. yes. I am running 14.15. 4. What you recommend as the best steps to correct the issue? Thanks

Comment: Yeah sorry, I don't use BlueHost and I don't think you issue is related to the `npm` version running. Have you followed BlueHost's documentation on deploying a nodejs application?  How do you know it isn't running? Perhaps it is running and unreachable due to some other needed configuration?

Comment: I also don't think the npm version running is the problem because if I cd into the directory and use ```/opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node app.js``` -- I'm returned with the server running on port... and then when going into the when going into the whm via root and use curl http://127.0.0.1:3000 -- I am returned with my entire index.ejs file. So it passed both test that the server is running, but yet the domain only returns "Index of/" ... with the directory folder. I've followed all the documentation quite carefully and have been on this for a week now. Now, double checking the cpanel.yml file